# How to undo desktop folder location change in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, desktop

I did change the desktop folder location to `D:` for security and backup. However now it seems to be that `D:` is some how incorporated in Desktop, like if they are only one unit?

How I can revert this? Go back to the original setting? Why it happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your desktop location to the root of the drive, (e.g. `D:\`), then yes, all contents on that drive would now be part of your Desktop.  Notice that generally the desktop location is `C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\`, a subdirectory, not the root `C:\`

As for reverting back, just use whatever directions you had before and reverse them.  You may need to copy files from D:\ to C:\Users\Desktop if you created new items.

Comment: Thanks Ernie, can you further explain. It seems to be that now D and the desktop are only one folder. It actualy appears as D in Users!!